# Перевод кода из python 2 в python 3: ошибка NameError: name 'file' is not defined

Tags: python

дан код, написанный на python 2

```
class Document(file):

    def __init__(self, filename, mode='rb', buffering=1, delete_on_close=True):
        file.__init__(self, filename, mode, buffering)
        self.delete_on_close = delete_on_close

    def close(self):
        file.close(self)
        if self.delete_on_close:
            self.delete()

    def delete(self):
        os.unlink(self.name)
```

При попытке запуска на 3 выскакивает ошибка:

```
class Document(file):
NameError: name 'file' is not defined
```

Подскажите, как исправить? Вроде как file удален в третей версии, а вместо него open()? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Есть похожий вопрос на en:so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085292/subclassing-file-objects-to-extend-open-and-close-operations-in-python-3

Comment: @alex-krass  Спасибо

Comment: Не помещайте решение (если оно работает  в вашем случае) в вопрос, опубликуйте его как ответ—[это явно приветствуется](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все оказалось банально:

```
class Document():

    def __init__(self, filename, mode='rb', buffering=1, delete_on_close=True):
        #file.__init__(self, filename, mode, buffering)
        self.file=open(filename, mode, buffering)
        self.delete_on_close = delete_on_close

    def close(self):
        self.file.close()
        if self.delete_on_close:
            self.delete()

    def delete(self):
        os.unlink(self.name)
```

Comment: Если duck-typing работает (решение в ответе), то оно предпочтительно наследованию, но если необходимо наследование по уважительным причинам, то посмотрите на классы в io модуле такие как FileIO, TextIOBase, etc.